# Draw median lines at appropriate height on a dodged dotplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, median, dot, crossbar

I measured a given behaviour in animals (males and females) of various reproductive states (from virgin to parent).

I am drawing a dotplot with dodged dots, and I would like to add a median bar for each subgroup. I previously asked a similar question, and I was told to use `stat_summary` with `geom="point"` to add a median bar (see example code below).

My problem is that the bar seems erratically placed around the real median value, instead of being accurately located on the median value (see plot below)

```
# Mock dataframe:
Sex<-rep(c("M","F"), times=12)
ID<-rep(seq(from=1, to=6), times=4)
Behavior<-rnorm(24, mean=10, sd=3)
State<-rep(c("virgin", "virgin", "mated", "mated", "expecting", "expecting", "parent", "parent"), times=3)
d<-data.frame(ID,Sex,Behavior,State)
d$State2=ifelse(d$Sex=="F", as.numeric(d$State) + 0.15, as.numeric(d$State) - 0.15) # horizontally dodging males to the left, females to the right

# The plot
b<-ggplot(d, aes(x=factor(State), y=Behavior, colour=factor(Sex)))+
  geom_dotplot(aes(x=State2, group=interaction(State, Sex), fill=Sex),binaxis="y", stackdir="center", stackratio=1.5, binwidth = 0.3, binpositions="all", dotsize=1)+
  stat_summary(aes(x=State2),fun.y = "median", geom="point", shape=45, size=20, show.legend = F, alpha=0.6) +
  labs(x="",y="Behavior")+
  geom_line(aes(x=State2, group=interaction(ID, Sex), color=Sex), alpha=0.5, size=0.2)+
  theme_classic()+ 
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = 1),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color="black", size = 1))+
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  theme(axis.text.x =element_text(size=10),axis.text.y=element_text(size=10), axis.title=element_text(size=11,face="bold"))+
  scale_fill_manual(name="Sex", values=c("brown2", "blue3"), breaks=c("F", "M"))+
  scale_colour_manual(name="Sex",values=c("brown2","blue3"),breaks=c("F", "M"),labels=c("Female", "Male"))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("virgin", "mated", "expecting", "parent"), labels=c("virgin"="Virgin", "mated"="Mated", "expecting"="Expecting", "parent"="Parent"))+
  theme(text=element_text(family="serif"))
b
```

[image: example plot with added lines and medians]

**Edit:** 
I have looked up other possibilities, like using `geom=crossbar` in the `stat_summary` statement, like so:
`stat_summary(aes(x=State2),fun.y = "median", fun.ymax="median", fun.ymin="median", geom="crossbar", show.legend = F) +`

But the problem is the same, the bars are not placed accurately...:
[image: example with crossbar]

**How can I easily add accurate median bars?** 
Thanks

Comment: FYI: the code provided produces an error. `Error in grid.newpage()`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `geom_point` instead of `geom_dotplot`

```
p<-ggplot(d, aes(x=factor(State), y=Behavior, colour=factor(Sex)))+

  geom_point(aes(x=State2, group=interaction(State, Sex), fill=Sex), size = 5)+

  stat_summary(aes(x=State2),fun.y = "median", geom="point", shape=45, size=20, show.legend = F, alpha=0.6) +
  labs(x="",y="Behavior")+
  geom_line(aes(x=State2, group=interaction(ID, Sex), color=Sex), alpha=0.5, size=0.2)+
  theme_classic()+ 
  theme(axis.line.x = element_line(color="black", size = 1),
        axis.line.y = element_line(color="black", size = 1))+
  theme(legend.position="none")+
  theme(axis.text.x =element_text(size=10),axis.text.y=element_text(size=10), axis.title=element_text(size=11,face="bold"))+
  scale_fill_manual(name="Sex", values=c("brown2", "blue3"), breaks=c("F", "M"))+
  scale_colour_manual(name="Sex",values=c("brown2","blue3"),breaks=c("F", "M"),labels=c("Female", "Male"))+
  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("virgin", "mated", "expecting", "parent"), labels=c("virgin"="Virgin", "mated"="Mated", "expecting"="Expecting", "parent"="Parent"))+
  theme(text=element_text(family="serif"))
```

BTW I don't think your data and x labels are matching because the `State` column in your `d` data frame is `factor` variable ordered alphabetically. You will need to reorder the levels `levels = c("virgin", "mated", "expecting", "parent")`

So it will be something like:

```
d<-data.frame(ID,Sex,Behavior,State)

# Reorder State levels
d$State <- factor(d$State, levels = c("virgin", "mated", "expecting", "parent"))

d$State2=ifelse(d$Sex=="F", as.numeric(d$State) + 0.15, as.numeric(d$State) - 0.15) # horizontally dodging males to the left, females to the right
```